# javascript prevent enterKey from adding new line

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, default

i am trying to submit the text in a textarea with the enterkey. thats working fine but the enterkey is always adding a new line before submitting the data...

i know that i have to use event.preventDefault() but it is not working for me.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
        var wrappedHandler, newValueAccessor;

        // wrap the handler with a check for the enter key
        wrappedHandler = function (data, event) {
            if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY && !event.shiftKey) {                   
                event.target.blur();
                valueAccessor().call(this, data, event);
            }
        };

        // create a valueAccessor with the options that we would want to pass to the event binding
        newValueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                keyup: wrappedHandler
            };
        };

        // call the real event binding's init function
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data);
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume you have a multi line text field? if you are not allowing return characters, can you not just use a single line text field?

Comment: yes it is a textarea. it must be a multiline field.

Answer (score 4):

You should call `event.preventDefault` on `keypress` event.
For example, code below prevents enter key pressing

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
        $(element).keypress(function(e) { 
            (e.keyCode == 13) {
               e.preventDefault();
               // do something else
            }
        })
    }
}
```